# Links linking to external site are not working in android tablet version with jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've got a big problem with links linking to external sites.

I'm using jQuery mobile 1.1.1 and jQuery 1.6.4, and I have them loaded in my HTML fail like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.popover.js"></script>
```

jQuery.popover are the popovers for tablet version, I'm using Phonegap and native part.

The problem is that the links linking to external source are not working: when I click on them, they do nothing.

I tried using `data-ajax="false"` , `rel="external"` and many more, but nothing happens.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you modified your domain whitelist file correctly to allow external access.

Open your file `res/xml/cordova.xml` and add `<access origin="*"/>`.

Normally, you would replace `*` with the external URL you want provide access to. But, to make sure that the problem really comes from the whitelist, we will use `*`.

For more information about domain whitelist, check the online doc: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Hope this helps. Let me know if this works for after modifying your domain whitelist file.